# Script/tool to import series of snapshots, each being a new revision, into Subversion, populating source tree?

Tags: svn, import, snapshot, series

I've developed code locally and taken a fairly regular snapshot whenever I reach a significant point in development, e.g. a working build.

So I have a long-ish list of about 40 folders, each folder being a snapshot e.g. in ascending date YYYYMMDD order, e.g.:-

1. 20100523
2. 20100614
3. 20100721
4. 20100722
5. 20100809
6. 20100901
7. 20101001
8. 20101003
9. 20101104
10. 20101119
11. 20101203
12. 20101218
13. 20110102

I'm looking for a script to import each of these snapshots as a new subversion revision to the source tree. The end result being that the HEAD revision is the same as the last snapshot, and other revisions are as numbered.

Some other requirements:

- that the HEAD revision is not cumulative of the previous snapshots, i.e., files that appeared in older snapshots but which don't appear in later ones (e.g. due to refactoring etc.) should not appear in the HEAD revision.
- meanwhile, there should be continuity between *files* that *do* persist between snapshots. Subversion should know that there are previous versions of these files and not treat them as brand new files within each revision.

Some background about my aim:

- I need to formally revision control this work rather than keep local private snapshot copies.
- I plan to release this work as open source, so version controlling would be highly recommended
- I am evaluating some of the current popular version control systems (Subversion and GIT) BUT I *definitely* need a working solution in Subversion. I'm *not* looking to be persuaded to use one particular tool, I need a solution for each tool I am considering as I would also like a solution in GIT (I will post an answer separately for GIT so separate camps of folks who have expertise in GIT and Subversion will be able to give focused answers on one or the other).

The same question but for GIT [Answered in programmers.stackexchange.com]:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33868/script-tool-to-import-series-of-snapshots-each-being-a-new-edition-into-git-po

An outline answer for Subversion in stackoverflow.com but not enough specifics about the script: what commands to use, code to check valid scenarios if necessary - i.e. a working script basically. [Is there anyway to import XCode snapshots into a new SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203818/is-there-anyway-to-import-xcode-snapshots-into-a-new-svn-repository)

(*Originally posted in programmers.stackexchange.com but published here since programmers includes subjective discussions where as stackoverflow.com is for precise question and answers (according to official comparison of sites (http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so) ).*

Comment: Is your code sitting on any kind of Subversion working copy?

Comment: +1 For a response :) thanks. No, the moment, the code is ordinary file folders. It does not reside within a working copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a standard tool available to do this job:

```
svn_load_dirs.pl
```

As stated as a solution to question in SVN Forum post "Import 50 manual full-backups": http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=5292

and

In SVN Forum question "Importing New Code into Repository": http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=4859

I expect to accept this, my own answer to my question.